# Why are all of my flags on low-quality answers being declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I have had a series of moderator-declined flags recently, a few of which I have come to accept subsequently, though most of them I do not agree.

I did not report this because I thought moderators and flaggers are alike, that we are only human. But the frequencies of the flags declined has progressively become so often that I thought I would make a post here on Meta.

---

**None** of these flags was flagged for moderator attention (except for the SPAM flag listed below); they were flags of Not An Answer.

---

The flags declined have occurred at around the same time frame, somewhere around 1AM Cambridge (UK) Time (or 2AM Berlin Time) and within a very short period of time after my flagging; as a result, my assumption is that they had not gotten a chance to go through the [Low Quality Post Review Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/stats), which would then be democratically reviewed by other users/reviewers.

Please have a look at the following declined flags:

**1.**

---

[image]

Link: [How can I make setInterval also work when a tab is inactive in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927284/how-can-i-make-setinterval-also-work-when-a-tab-is-inactive-in-chrome/41389187#41389187)

The reason I flagged it (I did not flag it for moderator attention; someone else must have, even though the decline reason seems to suggest that I did):

It is merely a comment in addressing that ***"Its better than one second lagging setTimeout"***.

Looking closely, one would see that it is actually a comment to the highly upvoted answer above, which mentions already the use of *"time"* and `setInterval` years before.

As an aside:

There was actually a comment by a 80K user before my flag took place, who also agreed that it was merely a comment, which should not be posted as an answer. But the comment has since been removed after my flagging of it, deleted perhaps by the same 80K herself/himself or by the moderator.

---

**2.**

[image]

Link: [What is the preferred way to store state between init and update for custom knockout binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166110/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-store-state-between-init-and-update-for-custom-knoc/41388819#41388819)

The reason I flagged it:

It is just a comment, not an attempt to provide an answer.

**3.**

---

[image]

Link: [Possible in Jenkins to add sleep time between build actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13378185/possible-in-jenkins-to-add-sleep-time-between-build-actions/41353642#41353642)

The reason I flagged it:

***"I added .... Start-Sleep -sec 240"***. Ok, without citing the purposes (the question has not mentioned the duration). I would have accepted it as a comment (I.e., *"I did the same thing, too"*), especially given that the question is 4-years old and has had already 3 answers, which appropriately addressed the issue since.

**4.**

---

[image]

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33922282/parse-an-english-sentence-into-a-pattern/41082047#41082047

The reason I flagged it:

I wouldn't normally flag even if the answer contains link(s).
This particular answer is only trying to promote a service, which the answerer proclaims having affiliation to; the service thereof promotes a service which has pricing.

In addition, I have seen the same user from review queue before, who had posted similar answer with link linking to this commercial service to questions that did not even ask for recommendation for services. Thus, I decided to flag it this time around.

**5.**

---

[image]

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40206534/using-wordpress-com-but-storing-files-elsewhere/40878150#40878150

This answer as well as the question has been deleted; I am not able to see it due to the fact that I am not a 10K user.

**6.**

---

[image]

Link: [Stack pointer of the interrupt stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32159700/stack-pointer-of-the-interrupt-stack/41111788#41111788)

The reason of my flagging of it:

I don't normally flag an answer just because it contains a question mark (or more) or for being short.
But for this particular case, it is really a comment with much uncertainty. Had the answerer said something for instance: *"Take a look at ....(referring to information the questioner posted). Used as a margin to avoid accidentally cross the boundary?"*, I would not have flagged it.

I hope someone (perhaps a Stack Overflow employee or other moderators) be so kind as to look into this.

Comment: On that spam flag that was declined: *(full disclosure - I co-founded crunchable)* does the trick because in the help it says *However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.* and they have some other posts that are not spam.

Comment: 1, 2, and 3 all read to me as attempts to answer the question. They all give potential solutions, and current policy is that those constitute answers. 4... It doesn't seem all that spammy to me. They give a method of a solution, then they give a product that can do that. It isn't an advertisement and they do disclose their affiliation. I'd have left this one alone personally. It doesn't feel worth the 100 rep penalty to me. 5 I can't see. _6_ looks like NAA to me. What kind of answer is that supposed to be? (Second look, it's a q to answer the second to last line of the actual q. Questionable)

Comment: All of those answers are answer.  None of them are "not an answer".  Most of them look like *bad* answers.  You don't flag an answer as NAA because you think it's a bad answer.  Downvote if it's a bad answer.  Flag it as NAA if it's *not an answer at all*, correct or incorrect, useful or useless.

Comment: @Kendra For 5 the question was deleted as it was offtopic, it got an answer that was attempting to answer the question.

Comment: You are beginning to see that flags are not a reliable way to get crap removed from the website. Moderators have been instructed to decline "not an answer" flag as long as the answer *pretends* to be an answer, and it gets most of the way there by being written in English and living in the answer box. It has to be a really egregious case before you can flag, and if you're anything like me, your definition of "egregious" will be different than others. It is why we cannot have nice things. Anyway, the solution to getting this crap removed is to downvote it. 10k+ users can then vote to delete.

Answer (score 26):

Just because an answer is short doesn't make it a comment or not an answer. If a short answer is attempting to answer the question, it should not be flagged as "not an answer". "Not an answer" flags are for things like gibberish, "me too" responses, and follow-on questions. These are all things that are obviously not trying to answer the question.

Many of the answers you flagged didn't suffer from any of these problems and they were actual answers. Some were even accepted and / or upvoted. This is also why I and other moderators declined your recent "not an answer" flags on each of these posts:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/40053092/19679
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/40143211/19679
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/40143475/19679
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/40143454/19679
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/40289533/19679
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/40477080/19679

Frankly, we've been declining a lot of your flags for months now in an attempt to express that these are not items that should be flagged. The fact that community review could only dispute instead of decline many of  these flags is the only reason that you haven't been banned from flagging on several occasions.

I highly recommend reviewing the hundreds of answers we've declined your flags on, and comparing those with the thousands of others we've marked as being helpful. Focus on the cases covered by the latter when flagging, and we'll be glad to process all of those.

Answer (score 17):

Let's not sugarcoat this - these are all *terrible* answers.

However, [they're still answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/175248).  They still make some feeble attempt to answer the question.

In this instance, the correct thing to do would be to downvote; moderators aren't suited to gauge correctness or determine factuality; we do that.

A complete non-answer would be someone posting a question guised as an answer, providing a spammy post with a link to some spammy site, or saying something offensive or otherwise untoward, which would warrant the moderator attention.  These are simply things we can downvote and disagree with instead.